# Insert.aspx.vb - Set focus to control in dynamic FormView

Tags: asp.net, formview

I am having a bit of trouble with a dynamic asp.net FormView (within Insert.aspx.vb) in my ASP.NET LINQ to SQL Website. Here is the code for the FormView...

```
        <asp:FormView runat="server" ID="FormView1" DataSourceID="DetailsDataSource" DefaultMode="Insert"
            OnItemCommand="FormView1_ItemCommand" OnItemInserted="FormView1_ItemInserted" RenderOuterTable="false">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <table id="detailsTable" class="DDDetailsTable" cellpadding="6">
                    <asp:DynamicEntity runat="server" Mode="Insert" />
                    <tr class="td">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
```

When this form is displayed in a browser, there are 5 user input controls, and two buttons (insert/cancel). But here in the code, I do not see any reference to the 5 user input controls, unless they are represented by this line of code...

```
    <asp:DynamicEntity runat="server" Mode="Insert" />
```

First, am I correct in assuming that this line of code builds the user input controls dynamically? 
And, my actual problem -- I need to set the Focus to the first of these input's upon page initialization. Basically when someone chooses to insert a new item and is sent to this page, I want them to be able to start typing right away, without the need to actually click in that textbox to begin. Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Dynamic Data Sites are great for quick setups, but once you start trying to customize their UIs and functionality, they quickly become a burden.  And I speak from experience.  I don't know how to customize the focus other than looking at the rendered HTML and then using JavaScript or jQuery to force the focus.  But I will tell you that if you plan for this application to be ever-changing, get away from Dynamic Data now before it's too late to change course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by adding a Search field via Code, and then using this in the Page_Load event...

```
    If table.DisplayName = "Employees" Then
        MultiSearchFieldSet.Visible = True
        txbMultiColumnSearch.Focus()
```